# Binomial distribution when k and p grow respectively

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I'm having two binomial cdf cases and I'm looking for the minimum number of samples to satisfy each one:

1. p = 0.1 and we want 90% probability to have 5 or more successes.
2. p = 0.3 and we want 90% probability to have 15 or more successes.

Intuitively it looks like the answer would be the same in both cases since p was tripled but k was as well. However I do understand the logic behind the difference in the amount of samples needed, but can't really prove it well or generalize it.
What is the mathematical reason for this difference?

Comment: At the level of accuracy of the normal approximation, what matters is not the ratio of the mean to the threshold, but the ratio of the difference between the mean and the threshold to the standard deviation. And although you tripled the difference between the mean and the threshold in going from 1 to 2 (for fixed $k$), you didn't triple the standard deviation.

Comment: And how does the standard deviation affects the samples we need to achieve a certain probability?

Comment: Thinking only intuitively, if you change $c$ from $5$ to $15$ and $p$ from $0.1$ to $0.3$ then the numerator in $\frac{c-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$ is tripled while the denominator goes from $\sqrt{0.09n}=0.3\sqrt{n}$ to $\sqrt{0.21n} \approx 0.46\sqrt{n}$. So the standard deviation is bigger but not 3 times bigger.

Comment: Specifically, the whole ratio is multiplied by about $\frac{3 \cdot 0.3}{0.46} \approx 1.96$, so $n$ can be chosen so that the original $\frac{c-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$ ratio is about 1.96 times smaller than before. What that means for the value of $n$ is translated through a quadratic equation, which muddles the intuition a fair bit.

Comment: I get how the variance changes depending on p, but I still can't put my finger on what causes the number of samples (n) to be different in each case. What property of this distribution makes the difference when calculating the number of attempts ?

Comment: Again, at the level of the normal approximation, what matters is the ratio $\frac{c-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$; this needs to be $\leq$ some negative constant in order to have $P(X \geq c)$ exceed some given threshold $\alpha>1/2$. In terms of the picture, the point is that when you increase $p$ and $c$ proportionally, the distance between $c$ and $np$ in units of standard deviations gets larger.

Comment: Got it, thanks!